# Unable to set default values on a ControllerCollection that is mounted

Tags: silex

When I mount a controller collection on a path, the default value does not work, I'm forced to provide a value.

```
// app.php
...
$app->mount('/path/', MyControllerProvider());
....    

// my controller provider
class MyControllerProvider implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
    public function connect(Application $app)
    {
        $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];

        $controllers->get('/{param}', function($param) {
             return $param;     
        })
        ->value('param','foo');
    }
}
```

When I try to visit /path/ I can following error:

NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /path/"

If I visit /path/somevalue then it works.

The default value works fine if you add a route to the main $app but not when mounting.

Comment: I managed to replicate your results, but I cannot tell why it works like this. I know that @igorw visits SO often, maybe he can answer. If you don't get a response in a few days, I suggest you open a ticket on github.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: Well a workaround at least, when I mount the controller, I don't include the trailing slash, this makes the default value work e.g. so visiting /path would return foo but /path/ would still throw error.

Answer (score 0):

Silex treats paths with and without trailing slash as a different paths. Issue about this is already posted on github: https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/issues/149.

You can try to register both paths to the same function (code will look little weird but should work).